# CoffeeScript multi value switch statement?

Tags: coffeescript

```
switch @user && @other
    when 'user' && true
        ...
    when 'user2' && false
       ...
```

Is something like this possible? It's not working for some reason. Thanks!

Comment: Could you define "not working"? That code compiles fine. Or were you expecting it to compare `user` to `'user'` and `@other` to `true`? If that's the case, there's no way to get `switch` to do what you want; you should either use `if`/`else` or write a function.

Comment: Ah ok. Yes I was looking to have user compare to 'user' and other to true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a pity that JS doesn't think `[1, 2] === [1, 2]` (since they're different references); otherwise you could use arrays to do what you want.

Instead, here's a function:

```
multiSwitch = (values, cases...) ->
  for c in cases
    match = true
    for i in [0...values.length]
      unless c[i] is values[i]
        match = false
        break
    return c[values.length]() if match
  return
```

Use it like this:

```
multiSwitch [@user, @other],
  ['user', true, ->
    console.log 'case 1'
  ]
  ['user2', false, ->
    console.log 'case 2'
  ]
```

Depending on what you're doing, it may be easier to, say, concatenate your multiple values into a string and do a `switch` on that.